# Nested CollectionType Save Entity in ArrayCollection

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

i want to store some data

```
class Offer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array")
     */
    private $meterPoints;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->meterPoints = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

for an offer as a CollectionType.

```
class OfferType extends AbstractType
{
    $builder
        ->add('meterPoints', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => OfferMeterPointType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'prototype_name' => '__mp_name__',
        ))
}
```

In the OfferMeterPointType I also have an EntityType

```
class OfferMeterPointType extends AbstractType
{
    $builder
        ->add('meterPoint', EntityType::class, array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'chosen-select'
            ),
            'class' => 'AppBundle:MeterPoint',
            'choice_label' => 'meterPoint',
        ))
        ->add('billData', CollectionType::class, array(
            'label' => false,
            'entry_type' => OfferBillType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'entry_options' => array(
                'label' => false
            )
        ));

}
```

Now when I persist that entity the whole AppBundle:MeterPoint object get serialized and not just the id. I kind of understand why doctrine does that but can I change it such that just the id will be stored?

Also when I want to edit an Offer

```
$offer = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Offer')->findOneById(2);
$form = $this->createForm(OfferType::class, $offer);
```

i get an Exception

> Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?

I guess a solution would be to create an Entity for the OfferMeterPointType but I don't really want to do that. Because I allmost never need that data.

**Update**

I tried like martin suggested. now the exception is gone but it still saves the complete object

```
$meterPoints = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:MeterPoint')->findAll();
    //dump($meterPoints);
    $builder
        ->add('meterPoint', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label' => 'offerMeterPoint.meterPoint',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'chosen-selesct',
                'placeholder' => 'ob.to'
            ),
            'choices' => $meterPoints,
            'choice_label' => function($meterPoint) {
                return $meterPoint->getMeterPoint();
            },
            'choice_value' => function($meterPoint) {
                if($meterPoint === null){
                    return null;
                }
                dump($meterPoint);
                return $meterPoint->getId();
            },
            'placeholder' => 'global.plz_select'
        ))
```

**Update 2**
Got it working 
changed the ChoiceType

```
        $meterPoints = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:MeterPoint')->findAll();
    $mps = array();
    foreach($meterPoints as $mp){
        $mps [$mp->getMeterPoint()] = $mp->getId();
    }
    //dump($meterPoints);
    $builder
        ->add('meterPoint', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label' => 'offerMeterPoint.meterPoint',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'chosen-selesct',
                'placeholder' => 'ob.to'
            ),
            'choices' => $mps,
            'placeholder' => 'global.plz_select'
        ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You get a object serialized because your column type is `array` and `EntityType` automatically replaces choice values with objects.

   There's however [`choice_value`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-value) that accepts also a callable so I'd try fiddling with it and maybe you can get it to return just the id (maybe force string type?).

   If this doesn't help then probably use just `ChoiceType` and handle the logic yourself.
2. This happens because Doctrine automatically deserializes the objects from `$meterPoints` that you try to use as entities with `EntityType`. These objects are obviously not managed by the Doctrine Entity manager. Thus the error.

   I think you'll have to convert the `$meterPoints` to database entities before using `$this->createForm(...)` yourselves if you want to avoid creating more relations. Eventually and maybe even easier approach would be writing a custom Doctrine type that could do this for you:

   - http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html